# NoMethodError in Post#index undefined method `each' for #<Post:0x9c01d58>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner in Rails. I want to show the list of post which comes under specific topic.
This is my controller:

```
      def index
        @posts = Post.find(params[:topic_id])
      end
```

This is my view:

```
     <% @posts.each do |p| %>
        <tr>
          <td> <%= p.user_id %> </td>
          <td> <%= p.title %> </td>
          <td> <%= p.content %> </td>
          <td> <i> <%= p.created_at %> </i> </td>
          <td> <%= link_to 'Show Post', post_path(p) %> </td>
          <td> <%= link_to 'Delete Post', post_path(p), method: :delete %> </td>
          <td> <%= link_to 'Update Post', edit_post_path(p) %> </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

I am receiving an error which is `NoMethodError in Post#index (undefined method 'each' for #<Post:0x9c01d58>)`. I don't know what is the error. Can you please explain where the error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Post.find(params[:topic_id])` retrieves one instance of `Post` model, not array.

`@posts = Post.all` retrieves all posts

`@posts = Post.where(topic_id: params[:topic_id])` retrieves all posts for topic

`@posts = Post.where(user_id: params[:user_id])` retrieves all user's posts

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know what is the error

`Post.find` returns one post. Naturally, it doesn't respond to `each`, since it's just one post, not a collection of posts.

What you probably wanted is this:

```
@posts = Post.where(topic_id: params[:topic_id])
```

but it's hard to tell.